# Exit code error encountered when terminating 'yarn start' command with Ctrl+C

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vite

When executing the command 'yarn start' and attempting to terminate it using Ctrl+C, I encounter an exit code error."

Question:
"When I run the 'yarn start' command and subsequently terminate it with Ctrl+C, I receive the following error message: 'Command failed with exit code 1.' How can I resolve this issue?

Error:
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: I would also like to know how to solve this aesthetically displeasing behavior...